# IOS Notificaciones Push

Tags: firebase, ios, swift, push-notification

Tengo una app desarrollada en Swift la cual necesito que reciba notificaciones. Investigue y la única forma que encontre es hacerlo con push notifications usando firebase. La notificación la voy a lanzar desde una app .NET usando el email del usuario.

Esta bien si uso cloud functions en la cual reciba el email y se autentique con `firebase.auth` para obtener el `uid` de usuario, y luego escriba el mensaje en la realtime database, y luego con otra función envie el mensaje push? El problema es que la app .NET solo tiene los correos del usuario, no puedo obtener los token que genera firebase.

Answer (score 0):

También podrías optar por usar OneSignal. Es sencillo de implementar, por cada device registra el uuid y ese parámetro lo ligas a un usuario registrado y ya con eso puedes enviar la notificación desde la app .net

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/sending-notifications